# Using a conditional sum to check whether data in a moving observation window meets certain criteria in SAS

Tags: conditional-statements, sas

See tables `have` and `want` below for the sample code and expected output.

Using this data set, I would like SAS code that will output values in a new column. Call the new column "RuleHit". The code should group by ID. The logic for the new column will output "1" if the logic is satisfied and "0" if it is not. The logic will first sum the number of occurrences of "B" in column "RuleHit" for all lagged observations within 8 months based on its "datetime" value. If the sum of those "B" values within the 8-month window is greater or equal to 2, then RuleHit equals "1". If the sum of those values is less than 2, then RuleHit equals 0.

The challenge here is that the number of lags for each observation can change. All my efforts have failed so far. Any help would be appreciated.

INPUT:

```
data have;
  input id datetime :datetime. event $;
  format datetime datetime.;
  datalines;
1 01JAN2022:00:00:00 A
1 15APR2022:11:46:34 B
1 23JUN2022:01:02:10 A
1 22JAN2023:14:32:58 A
1 08JUN2023:16:10:32 B
1 11JUL2023:20:39:51 A
1 28JAN2023:21:41:35 A
1 09APR2023:11:22:17 A
1 16MAY2023:22:14:23 B
1 13NOV2022:08:08:56 B
2 06FEB2022:09:23:43 B
2 12MAY2022:07:55:09 A
2 25JUN2022:08:26:44 B
2 03OCT2022:09:54:03 A
2 05DEC2022:01:51:06 A
2 12JUL2022:10:14:44 B
2 20SEP2022:16:39:51 A
2 01JAN2023:01:18:57 A
2 28MAR2023:12:46:34 B
2 05JUN2023:07:32:10 A
3 28FEB2022:23:08:58 A
3 02APR2022:05:22:17 B
3 21JUN2022:22:01:43 B
3 10AUG2022:18:36:23 A
3 13NOV2022:20:45:19 A
3 24DEC2022:17:37:57 B
3 18MAR2023:19:41:35 A
3 06MAY2023:15:22:17 A
3 09JUL2023:02:14:23 B
3 21OCT2023:14:08:56 B
;
run;
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT:

```
data want;
  input id datetime :datetime. event $ RuleHit;
  format datetime datetime.;
  datalines;
1 01JAN2022:00:00:00 A 0
1 15APR2022:11:46:34 B 0
1 23JUN2022:01:02:10 A 0
1 22JAN2023:14:32:58 A 0
1 08JUN2023:16:10:32 B 0
1 11JUL2023:20:39:51 A 0
1 28JAN2023:21:41:35 A 0
1 09APR2023:11:22:17 A 0
1 16MAY2023:22:14:23 B 1
1 13NOV2022:08:08:56 B 1
2 06FEB2022:09:23:43 B 0
2 12MAY2022:07:55:09 A 0
2 25JUN2022:08:26:44 B 1
2 03OCT2022:09:54:03 A 1
2 05DEC2022:01:51:06 A 0
2 12JUL2022:10:14:44 B 0
2 20SEP2022:16:39:51 A 0
2 01JAN2023:01:18:57 A 0
2 28MAR2023:12:46:34 B 0
2 05JUN2023:07:32:10 A 0
3 28FEB2022:23:08:58 A 0
3 02APR2022:05:22:17 B 0
3 21JUN2022:22:01:43 B 1
3 10AUG2022:18:36:23 A 1
3 13NOV2022:20:45:19 A 1
3 24DEC2022:17:37:57 B 1
3 18MAR2023:19:41:35 A 0
3 06MAY2023:15:22:17 A 0
3 09JUL2023:02:14:23 B 1
3 21OCT2023:14:08:56 B 1
;
run;
```

Comment: You sample data is not ordered by datetime within id. Is it important to maintain the original row order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably better not to think of it as a LAG problem.  Instead just do a self-join.

```
proc sql;
create table want as 
select a.*
     , sum(b.event='B') as num_hits
     , (calculated num_hits > 1) as RuleHit
from have a
left join have b
 on a.id = b.id
 and b.datetime between intnx('dtmonth',a.datetime,-8,'same') and a.datetime
group by a.id,a.datetime,a.event
;
quit;
```

Results

```
                                                         Rule
Obs    id               datetime    event    num_hits     Hit

  1     1     01JAN2022:00:00:00      A          0         0
  2     1     15APR2022:11:46:34      B          1         0
  3     1     23JUN2022:01:02:10      A          1         0
  4     1     13NOV2022:08:08:56      B          2         1
  5     1     22JAN2023:14:32:58      A          1         0
  6     1     28JAN2023:21:41:35      A          1         0
  7     1     09APR2023:11:22:17      A          1         0
  8     1     16MAY2023:22:14:23      B          2         1
  9     1     08JUN2023:16:10:32      B          3         1
 10     1     11JUL2023:20:39:51      A          3         1
 11     2     06FEB2022:09:23:43      B          1         0
 12     2     12MAY2022:07:55:09      A          1         0
 13     2     25JUN2022:08:26:44      B          2         1
 14     2     12JUL2022:10:14:44      B          3         1
 15     2     20SEP2022:16:39:51      A          3         1
 16     2     03OCT2022:09:54:03      A          3         1
 17     2     05DEC2022:01:51:06      A          2         1
 18     2     01JAN2023:01:18:57      A          2         1
 19     2     28MAR2023:12:46:34      B          1         0
 20     2     05JUN2023:07:32:10      A          1         0
 21     3     28FEB2022:23:08:58      A          0         0
 22     3     02APR2022:05:22:17      B          1         0
 23     3     21JUN2022:22:01:43      B          2         1
 24     3     10AUG2022:18:36:23      A          2         1
 25     3     13NOV2022:20:45:19      A          2         1
 26     3     24DEC2022:17:37:57      B          2         1
 27     3     18MAR2023:19:41:35      A          1         0
 28     3     06MAY2023:15:22:17      A          1         0
 29     3     09JUL2023:02:14:23      B          2         1
 30     3     21OCT2023:14:08:56      B          2         1
```

Comment: Nice, thanks for the explanation. A better way to approach the problem for sure.

Answer (score 0):

"all lagged observations within 8 months" would indicate the current datetime of a 'B' event should be excluded from the window.

`INTCK` will count intervals. According to docs, "The continuous method is useful for calculating anniversaries. ... The discrete method counts interval boundaries (for example, end of month).

Here is self-join with some features that reduce internal crossing combinations within `on` criteria.

- A reasonable hard backward boundary is specified to prevent window from going to first date of an `id`.  Will reduce number of `INTCK`s being done.
- The window event is limited to 'B'
- `Between` is not used to prevent counting 'now' Bs

```
proc sql; 
  create table want as
  select
    each.id
  , each.datetime
  , each.event
  , count(window.event) as freq
  , count(window.event) > 1 as flag label = 'flag_bfreq_gt_1_prior8mo' format=4.
  from 
    have as each
  left join 
    have as window
  on 
    each.id = window.id
    and window.datetime < each.datetime             /* exclude the 'now' B */
    and window.datetime > each.datetime-9*30*86400  /* hard bottom of roughly 9 month */
    and window.event = 'B'
    and intck('dtmonth'
              , window.datetime
              , each.datetime
              , 'continuous') <= 8
  group each.id, each.datetime, each.event
  ;
```